# How to execute a Doctrine migration with another connection in Symfony? (with DoctrineMigrationsBundle 3.0.x)

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I develop a Symfony app, using DoctrineBundle and DoctrineMigrationsBundle. The versions of the doctrine and Symfony dependencies are as follow:

`composer.json`

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        ...
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        ...
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.1.*",
        ...
    },
   ...
}
```

For security reasons, I want to use two different connections to the database, the `default` one with a database user which has SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE rights on tables used by the application - basically, all rights on data, it is the "application user" - and another one, `migrations`, with a database user which has rights on structure: CREATE, ALTER, DROP... on tables.

Both connections are defined in configuration:

`config/packages/doctrine.yaml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
                server_version: '11.1'
                charset: UTF8
            migrations:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
                server_version: '11.1'
                charset: UTF8
```

With the previous versions of the bundles, in a Symfony 4.4 application, there were a `--db` option for the `doctrine:migration:migrate` command, which allowed to choose the connection to use to execute the migrations:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --db=migrations --no-interaction
```

But, in the 3.0.x version of the bundle, this option has disappeared. There is only the `--configuration` and `--db-configuration` options which seem likely to allow to achieve the same, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

**What I tried:**

- Added a second entity manager in `doctrine.yaml`, to use the `migrations` connection (no mappings - I want to use it just to execute migrations, which are SQL commands):

`doctrine.yaml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
                charset: UTF8
            # Used to execute database migrations - conection with the owner user
            migrations:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
                charset: UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true

        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                auto_mapping: true
            # Used to create and execute database migrations
            migrations:
                connection: migrations
```

- I kept the default `config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml`, which uses the default entity manager, and added a second file:

`doctrine_migrations_db_owner.yaml`

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations'
    em: migrations
```

- Launched the migrations with this file:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --configuration=./config/packages/doctrine_migrations_db_owner.yaml
```

But, I have an error about the `doctrine_migrations` key in the yaml file... I tried to remove it, but then another error on the `migrations_paths`...

Does anyone can provide hints on how to use this option, or another solution, to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended with a solution, wich is, in my opinion, even cleaner that what I was doing with the previous version of the Doctrine migrations Bundle.

In the application, I use only the default database url (defined as an environment variable, or in `.env`):

```yaml
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
        charset: UTF8
```

```yaml
# config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
        # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
        'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations'
```

And, when I want to execute a migration with a privileged database user, defined in a `DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_URL` variable, I pass it as env var directly in the command:

```sh
DATABASE_URL="$DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_URL" php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

The variable is defined as follow:

```sh
DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_URL="postgresql://$DB_OWNER:$DB_OWNER_PASS@$DB_HOST:5432/$DB_NAME?serverVersion=$PG_VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and here is how I solved it:

In my **doctrine.yaml**, i added 2 different dbal connections:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    connections:
      default:
...
      migrations_conn:
...
```

In my **doctrine_migrations.yaml**, i added a **connection** property referencing the connection i wanted to use only for migrations:

```
doctrine_migrations:
  connection: migrations_conn
...
```